# Detecting changes on Backbone Model without distinct view

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, local-storage, marionette, backbone-model

I have a model in which I am using in multiple views. I want to detect a change event on that model (save it to localStorage for persistent) but I want the change to be independent of each view.

Is there a way to bind a model change event on the model itself, or in the controller (I'm also using Marionette and Require)? Here is my model:

```
define([
'backbone',
'common'
],
function(Backbone, Common) {

//Define the App Namespace before anything else
var APP = Common.app_namespace || {};

APP.Models.UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  //Set up default values 
  defaults: {
    "value" : "default"
    }

});

});
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking of using [backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) but (please please please correct me if I'm wrong) I think that the model in question needs to be in a collection, but since I don't need a collection, I was hoping to do this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone.Model extends Backbone.Events, so yes, it can listen and trigger events:

```
APP.Models.UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //Set up default values 
  defaults: {
    "value" : "default"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.myCallback);
  }
});
```

[And so on...](http://backbonejs.org/#Events)